# Compare two columns in DevExpress Web MVC GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, aspxgridview, devexpress-mvc

I'd like to know how to enable the UI filter builder and/or header row filter to compare two columns in gridview for DevExpress.Web MVC. For instance columns A and B are both integers and I want to create a filter for Column A >= Column B. This would be so the user could do this.

I haven't seen an example or know where to find that info in settings or other places.

Comment: Well it depends on when you want to do the comparison. "_I'd like to know how to compare x & y_" is pretty broad considering the amount of options you have to do so, or more to the point, when you wish to do so.

Comment: Hi gabe, true true.  I'd like to enable the user in the filter builder (and/or header row filter) on the UI.  I updated the question to be clearer. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called [`ASPxGridViewSettings.ShowFilterBar`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewSettings_ShowFilterBartopic) that you need to enable to show the [`Filter Bar Control`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5139).

It's a built in module so you don't need to worry about much else other than creating your default custom filter for said column, which, after setting that property appropriately should be easy.

See the [`ASPxGridViewSettings`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewSettingstopic) `class` documentation for more information.

Hope this helps

Comment: Gabe so the only way to do this is by setting it as a default filter?  The user can't specify in the filterbuilder [Column A] >= [Column B]?  It looks like you can do this in Winforms (example https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2567)

Comment: @user3086028 You can, just handle it the same way as the winforms version. It's pretty much an identical system. I was merely stating that if you wanted to set it up as default you could :)

Comment: Hi Gabe.  When I put in the column with the brackets it doesn't filter.  I noticed it puts the column name in single quotes. [Column A] is greater than or equal to '[Column B]' and it doesn't work...